# Is there a way to webscrape an iframe from Etherscan.io using R and rvest?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, iframe, rvest

I'm attempting to webscrape information from the following URL: https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances

Specifically the table on the bottom half of the page. I want the content of the "copy address" buttons shown in the picture:

[image]

My attempts have mostly boiled down to the following:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

  page = read_html("https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances")
  x = page %>% html_nodes(".js-clipboard") %>% html_attr("data-clipboard-text")
```

I understand that the table is an iframe and is essentially another html file. But I'm struggling to access the URL for that html. and when I inspect the html page to manually extract that iframe URL (/token/generic-tokenholders2m=dim&a=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&s=39025187376288180&sid=e88ba71b362fc00233af8a8db211da32&p=1) I still can't obtain my desired content.

My guess is that I'm not digging deep enough into the html structure to reach what I'm looking for, any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what browser you are using, but in Firefox, you can right click on iframes, and open them in a new tab. That's how I got the URL for it. And luckily, all of the addresses were in the HTML, so Javascript wasn't needed:

```
library(rvest)

url = "https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokenholders2?&a=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&s=39025187376288180&p=1" 

# the html_nodes gets the elements with class js-clipboard, then html_attr gets the data-clipboard-text attribute for each of those
# it would be straightforward to get the names too, if you want. But also, a good challenge for you, too! :-D
url |> read_html() |> html_nodes(".js-clipboard") |> html_attr("data-clipboard-text")
```

Output:

```
[1] "0xF977814e90dA44bFA03b6295A0616a897441aceC"
 [2] "0x47ac0Fb4F2D84898e4D9E7b4DaB3C24507a6D503"
 [3] "0xA7A93fd0a276fc1C0197a5B5623eD117786eeD06"
 [4] "0xcEe284F754E854890e311e3280b767F80797180d"
 [5] "0xD6216fC19DB775Df9774a6E33526131dA7D19a2c"
 [6] "0x40ec5B33f54e0E8A33A975908C5BA1c14e5BbbDf"
 [7] "0x5754284f345afc66a98fbB0a0Afe71e0F007B949"
 [8] "0x3CC936b795A188F0e246cBB2D74C5Bd190aeCF18"
 [9] "0x28C6c06298d514Db089934071355E5743bf21d60"
[10] "0xc5451b523d5FFfe1351337a221688a62806ad91a"
[11] "0x6Fb624B48d9299674022a23d92515e76Ba880113"
[12] "0x461249076B88189f8AC9418De28B365859E46BfD"
[13] "0xc708A1c712bA26DC618f972ad7A187F76C8596Fd"
[14] "0x69a722f0B5Da3aF02b4a205D6F0c285F4ed8F396"
[15] "0x42436286A9c8d63AAfC2eEbBCA193064d68068f2"
[16] "0xCbA38020cd7B6F51Df6AFaf507685aDd148F6ab6"
[17] "0x5a52E96BAcdaBb82fd05763E25335261B270Efcb"
[18] "0x89e51fA8CA5D66cd220bAed62ED01e8951aa7c40"
[19] "0x0D0707963952f2fBA59dD06f2b425ace40b492Fe"
[20] "0xf59869753f41Db720127Ceb8DbB8afAF89030De4"
[21] "0x65A0947BA5175359Bb457D3b34491eDf4cBF7997"
[22] "0xe9172Daf64b05B26eb18f07aC8d6D723aCB48f99"
[23] "0x4D19C0a5357bC48be0017095d3C871D9aFC3F21d"
[24] "0x5C52cC7c96bDE8594e5B77D5b76d042CB5FaE5f2"
[25] "0x99C9fc46f92E8a1c0deC1b1747d010903E884bE1"
[26] "0x0162Cd2BA40E23378Bf0FD41f919E1be075f025F"
[27] "0x68841a1806fF291314946EebD0cdA8b348E73d6D"
[28] "0x96FDC631F02207B72e5804428DeE274cF2aC0bCD"
[29] "0xBDa23B750dD04F792ad365B5F2a6F1d8593796f2"
[30] "0x7eb6c83AB7D8D9B8618c0Ed973cbEF71d1921EF2"
[31] "0x06d3a30cBb00660B85a30988D197B1c282c6dCB6"
[32] "0x3D55CCb2a943d88D39dd2E62DAf767C69fD0179F"
[33] "0x9723b6d608D4841eB4Ab131687a5D4764eb30138"
[34] "0x313Eb1C5e1970EB5CEEF6AEbad66b07c7338d369"
[35] "0x276cdBa3a39aBF9cEdBa0F1948312c0681E6D5Fd"
[36] "0x5041ed759Dd4aFc3a72b8192C143F72f4724081A"
[37] "0xc7C8f8284c5360D0086a2f0A05BdD07AFdE23246"
[38] "0xbEbc44782C7dB0a1A60Cb6fe97d0b483032FF1C7"
[39] "0xee5B5B923fFcE93A870B3104b7CA09c3db80047A"
[40] "0xEEA81C4416d71CeF071224611359F6F99A4c4294"
[41] "0xDD47B8411c2fe553fDDBE8E43099ab5C89B0bB25"
[42] "0x55C11477577636024F8c4e776CdA758c6f81cDaf"
[43] "0x4Ee7bBc295A090aD0F6db12fe7eE4dC8de896400"
[44] "0x77134cbC06cB00b66F4c7e623D5fdBF6777635EC"
[45] "0x8A446971dbB112f3be15bc38C14D44B94D9E94b9"
[46] "0x661Be0562b31E9E8DdC2A7c93803005A1C71D749"
[47] "0x2060ca911d52Ac785484B332480B7329765268aA"
[48] "0x82E1d4DDd636857Ebcf6a0e74B9b0929C158D7FB"
[49] "0x3fe705e2FFcaEe8d7287de047DeF35Db3e794C76"
[50] "0x8558FE88F8439dDcd7453ccAd6671Dfd90657a32"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was making a super dumb mistake. I was using attaching the full iframe URL to this URL: "https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances" Instead of just attaching it to the base URL

Comment: as a follow up question, I'm trying to perform something similar from an iframe at the following URL: https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7?a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec

I obtained the iframe URL using the method you described. Using a similar method as you outlined previously, I can't seem to grab data of interest such as the "Txn Hash" column. It seems R isn't seeing the same URL that opens in browser. I looked a little more into it and tried opening the URL in a private browser, to which it returned an error. I'll comment the URL below!

Comment: https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=dim&contractAddress=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec&sid=549ee0764b0bd57f0f1c7ae16f1ecefc&p=1

Comment: @NickAmato 1. did you get the url for the iframe? 2. did you use inspect element to get the important info for the thing you want to scrape? 3. what happened when you plugged it into rvest?

Comment: I got the URL from the from right clicking the iframe and selecting "view frame source" (i'm using chrome).  Now for example say I want to do what was done before, grab what is stored on the "data-clipboard-text" of the ".js-clipboard". The following code was used but yields no result. `page2=read_html(paste0("https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=dim&contractAddress=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec&sid=9d40509de6ec51ffb875259e1234d427&p=1"))
x2 = page2 %>% html_nodes(".js-clipboard") %>% html_attr("data-clipboard-text")`

Comment: in addition, the reason I think it's landing on the error page is because I tried this code `page2 = read_html(paste0("https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=dim&contractAddress=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec&sid=9d40509de6ec51ffb875259e1234d427&p=1"))x2 = page2 %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text()`. Which yielded text from the error landing page

Comment: oops okay the first url (https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7?a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec) works, but not the second(https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=dim&contractAddress=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec&sid=549ee0764b0bd57f0f1c7ae16f1ecefc&p=1)

Comment: and neither of the URLS in your rvest code comments above. Open them in a browswer, they redirect to https://etherscan.io/error

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the issue, the landing page gives an error for YOU (and R). However, If I copy and paste the URL from my `page2=` code above, into a browser I get an actual landing page with the iframe table. listing that link again (straight from my browser that is actually loading the page instead of erroring) so I can assure you it's the same as above [link](https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=dim&contractAddress=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec&sid=9d40509de6ec51ffb875259e1234d427&p=1).

Comment: try clearing your cookies, and then try opening it again. Do you get the same result?

Comment: I notice the link you posted that's erroring out has a different 'sid' argument in the URL than the code listed above in the `page2=` code.  Possibly why it's erroring out for you?

Comment: no, the one you linked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77046396/is-there-a-way-to-webscrape-an-iframe-from-etherscan-io-using-r-and-rvest/77046988?noredirect=1#comment135835871_77046988) post does the same. Did you try clearing cookies?

Comment: After clearing cookies I can still get my link to open successfully. However, If I open that SAME link in an incognito tab, It errors out.

Comment: And I didn't clear cookies from far enough back, it is also error in not incognito tab as well. My mistake

Comment: I was guessing that perhaps you were logged into the website

Comment: anyway, do you need to use that particular url? Doesn't the other one show the same information?

Comment: (https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7?a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec) Contains the information of interest, but it's in an iframe. For example if I want the "Age" variable from that table in the iframe, I can't get that without the iframe URL, correct?

Comment: try https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=light&contractAddress=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec&sid=c3b3dc04fa8942d681d04317109aa0b5&p=1

Comment: Unfortunately that one errors out for me

Comment: hmmm odd! it seems like maybe there's a cookie generated on the fly, and if you don't have that cookie it won't load for you

Comment: you might be able to get the iframe URL from the first link (https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7?a=0xf977814e90da44bfa03b6295a0616a897441acec), and then get the iframe URL, and then scrape that

Comment: two updates: 1. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjHG6.png) happened, and 2., there is a csv export on the page, scraping is unnecessary

Comment: The issue with the csv export is this table is being fed into an app (say it needs to be updated once a day). Since the export page requires the "i'm not a robot" input, it can't be automated correct?

Comment: probably not yeah

Comment: My only other idea would be to take a screenshot of the webpage (through R) that contains the info of interest, and then do some sort of text extraction to grab the info. But that sounds inefficient to say the least haha